# RCTImageLoader.h not found after adding react-navigation@^4.0.0

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

[image]
The error seems to be coming from RNScreens.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a react native project with v0.60.6
2. Add [react-navigation v4](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/getting-started/)
3. Add dependencies by [following](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/stack-navigator) [tutorial](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/getting-started/).
4. Add AppContainer and StackNavigator.
5. Build project in IOS.

Example minimal repo:
https://github.com/joshua-augustinus/react-navigation-training

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to downgrade react-native-screens to version: 2.11.0